# Cambiar el orden de las palabras de un String en java

Tags: java, bucles, caracteres, string

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo cambiar el orden de las palabras de un String usando solo bucles y los métodos charAt, length, trim.
Por ejemplo, si pongo "hola mundo" que lo cambie a "mundo hola", la idea sería que comprobara cada carácter y genere una nueva string con el orden de las palabras cambiado.

Me gustaría que fuera un código sencillo, sin usar el método Split, reverse, ni arrays ni nada de eso.

He intentado hacer esto pero no funciona:

```
import cs1.*;
public class reverse 
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      int longitud_cadena,longitud_cadena2;
      char caracter, caracter_b;
      String cadena, cadena_inv, NewString,test;

      System.out.printf("CADENA: ");
      cadena = Keyboard.readString();

      cadena = cadena.trim();
      longitud_cadena = cadena.length()-1;
      longitud_cadena2 = 0;
      NewString = "";
      cadena_inv = "";

      int i;
      int j;
      for(i=longitud_cadena; i>=0; i--)
      {
         caracter=cadena.charAt(i);
         cadena_inv +=caracter;
         longitud_cadena2 = cadena_inv.length()-1;
         if (caracter==' ')
         {
            for (j = longitud_cadena2; j>=0; j--)
            {
               caracter_b=cadena_inv.charAt(j);
               NewString +=caracter_b;       
            }
         }          
      }
      NewString = NewString.trim();
      System.out.println(NewString); 
   }
}
```

Cuando pongo por ejemplo: hola mundo prueba, me aparece prueba mundo prueba
Muchas gracias.

Comment: hola @sphinx, bienvenido a la comunidad, pero te pido de favor que primero leas [como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Adicional a esto lee ["¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo) para que evites recibir votos negativo en un futuro, En este caso aplica [que no intentaste ninguna solucion](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874)

Comment: se mas especifico al decir que no te funciona, por favor por cuales son los resultados y/o errores que recibes con ese codigo.

Comment: cual seria el resultado esperado? `prueba mundo hola`?

Comment: Si, pero no consigo hacerlo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda de verdad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que identificar son las palabras, entonces, sabemos que un espacio divide a dos palabras. Para esto hay que recorrer la candena caracter por caracter hasta encontrarlo. Asi que dentro tu `for` pones el siguiente `if`;

`if(cadena.charAt(i) != ' ')`

Es necesario llevar contadores que te permitan saber en que posicion de la cadena estas, para eso usas `i`, pero tambien es necesario saber de que caracter a que caracter hay una palabra por lo que sera necesario tener variables como `inicioPalabra` y `finPalabra`, las usarias algo asi:

```
//recuerda que las posiciones en cadenas y arreglos empiezan en cero
//entonces el ultimo caracter estara en la posicion longitud-1
int inicioPalabra=longitud_cadena-1;
int finPalabra=inicioPalabra;

String nuevaCadena = "";
//EDICION: esta sera una bandera para determinar si nos quedan caracteres por extraer o no
int caracteresRestantes = 0;

for(i=longitud_cadena -1 ; i>=0; i--)
{
   //recorrer la cadena hasta encontrar un espacio
   if(cadena.charAt(i) != ' ')
   {
      //recorremos el indice del caracter
      finPalabra--;
      caracteresRestantes++;
      continue;
   }

   //agregas a una nueva cadena la palabra que encontraste
   //es decir, los caracteres desde el inicio de la palabra hasta el final
   // EDICION: como estas recorriendo desde el final al inicio, el find la palabra seria realmente el inicio
   nuevaCadena+=cadena.substring(finPalabra, inicioPalabra) + " ";

   //EDICION: no es necesario decrementar nuevamente el indice

   //reinicias las posiciones de palabras
   finPalabra--;
   inicioPalabra = finPalabra;
   caracteresRestantes=0;
}

//si hay caracteres restantes, quiere decir que llego al final de la cadena y nunca encontro un espacio
//esto es normal, ya que las cadenas no siempre terminan con espacio
if( caracteresRestantes > 0){
   nuevaCadena+=cadena.substring(finPalabra, inicioPalabra);
}
```

**NOTA**: El codigo no esta provado por que no tengo Java instalado, pero es para que te des una idea. Pero te dejo un codigo en [Go](https://play.golang.org/p/8dDa4OC7Non), espero te sirva.

Comment: Me aparece este error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5

Comment: ese error es por que el indice del substring estaba mal, el inicio del substring era mayor al final

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!